# springboottest how to prevent running application

Tags: spring-boot, springjunit4classrunner

I have the standard Application class which runs a Spring batch ETL:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

with my Junit test doing something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void testInsertions() {
        //do stuff with assertions
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I execute the junit test, the application also kicks off the ETL then executes the test. How to prevent the application from running?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of alternatives and it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

One of the options would be to run your tests with a specific profile, like `testing`, and configure your ETLs *(I'm assuming they are just jobs)* to be configured based on some property or specific profile.

*For example:*

**Testing class**

```
@ActiveProfiles("testing")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {
    ...
}
```

**Job/ETL classes**

```
@Component
@Profile("!testing")
public class JobEtlService {
}
```

Hope it helps.